# OpenCL subbuffers, why is important?

Tags: communication, opencl, multi-gpu

I try to implement a multi-gpu OpenCL code. In my model, GPUs have to communicate and 
exchange data.

I found (I don't remember where, it is been some time) that one solution is to deal with 
subbuffers. Can anybody explain, as simple as possible, why subbuffers are important
in OpenCL? As far as I can understand, one can do exactly the same using only buffers.

Thanks a lot,
Giorgos

**Supplementary Question:**
 What is the best way to exchange data between GPUs?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure(or I do not know) how sub-buffers will provide solutions to your problem when dealing with Multiple GPU's. AFAIK sub buffers provide a view into a buffer i.e a single buffer can be divided into chunks of smaller buffers(sub buffers) providing a layer of software abstraction, Sub-buffers are advantageous in same cases where in you need keep an offset first element to be zero.

To address multiGPU or MultiDevice problem OpenCL 1.2 provides API from where you can copy memory objects directly from One GPU to other using `clEnqueueMigrateMemObjects` OpenCL API call http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMigrateMemObjects.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
So, subbufers are used only when somebody needs to keep an offset? There is no use in communication? I know about clEnqueueMigrateMemObjects but as far as I know version 1.2 is not implemented yet by nVidia.